# Xjc creates sub folders by the package specified

Tags: xsd, xjc

I'm trying to generate an xsd schema with xjc.
The problem is that the xjc creates sub folders by the -p (package) flag.

Example:

If ill run xjc from c: with -p a.b.c like this:

```
C:>xjc.exe -p a.b.c schema.xsd
```

The  xjc will create the a,b,c folders and the generated files will be located in c:/a/b/c

Even if ill specified a -d (directory) flag
Like this:

```
C:>xjc.exe -p a.b.c -d c:/files schema.xsd
```

The files will be located in c:/files/a/b/c

How can I get the xjc to not create this folders?

If I execute:

```
C:>xjc.exe -p a.b.c -d c:/files schema.xsd
```

The files will be located in c:/files,with package `a.b.c`.

Comment: Usually the Classes inside packages on your source tree, will be inside the directories, right? That's correct. Why do you want to create the files alone ?

Comment: because I'm using clear case to source control my project and the xjc run over these folder and erase all of their content.

Comment: You can use the `-d` flag to specify a directory which is kind-of `temp` where you can get the files generated and move them to your desired directory then. Is that not working for you?

Comment: I can do that, but the problem is that im using maven to build my project and im having a plugin so when the project builds, itll generate the files dynamicly. I dont want to move these files by myself, I want it to be created in that directory automatic when the project build.